# Cheap temperature sensor

Tags: temperature

For a project I need a cheap (less than 10 Euro) en simple solution to measure temperature. Accuracy is not really important, +/- 3 Degrees is acceptable. The desired temperature range is between 0 and 200 degrees.

One idea that I got was from a frying pan (see picture).

[image: temperature sensor]

considering frying pans costs around 15-20 euro's this must be a quite cheap solution, however I have no idea how such a sensor is called or works. Considering there is just a metal wire running from to probe to the control circuitry, I assume that heat gets transferred through the wire to a sensor on the PCB.

Please note that for this project the temperature sensor cannot be directly on the PCB itself

Comment: That's a capillary thermostat, not actually a sensor. It's not electrical, it's a mechanical thing that just happens to actuate an electrical switch. They're very common in cooking appliances.

Comment: What temperature range? What response time requirement? Will it be made waterproof? *Cheap* is not a specification.

Comment: Water proof is preferred, but not required. The desired temperature range is between 0 and 200 degrees (Celsius).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheapest reliable sensor for 200°C range is a thermocouple, but it requires relatively complex circuitry and a cold-junction sensor that is accurate to a degree or two to expect 3 degree accuracy. The sensor itself can be tens of cents.

A thin-film platinum RTD is still relatively inexpensive, but is interchangable (accurate as it arrives from the factory) but mounting a raw element is not necessarily easy. The sensor is two or three dollars and about the size of a 1206 resistor with leads off one end.

A hermetic glass diode (eg. 1N4148) could be used as a sensor, but every one will be a bit different (so you'd have to calibrate them individually to get 3 degrees accuracy) and 200°C is pushing it for reliability.

There are some glass thermistors which are claimed to be reliable at up to 250°C, but I am a bit skeptical, and they are not so inexpensive (eg. YSI).

There are bulk silicon sensors that look like glass diodes that are used in domestic ovens, suitable for the temperature range, but the accuracy might not quite get there.

**Edit:**  Seeing your < EUR 10 constraint, I would *definitely* go with the thin-film platinum sensor. The lowest grade (B grade) is good enough for you.

Comment: K-type thermocouple with cold-junction compensated digital temperature reading module for [just over 9 Euros, on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/MAX6675-Module-K-Type-Thermocouple-Thermocouple-Sensor-for-Arduino-/181440455042?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a3eb1a182). Uses the [MAX6675](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6675.pdf) IC, which is also on ebay for around $4 in single units.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Error is about double what he is asking for - 3°C in the cold junction and another couple °C in the amplifier/ADC. It's not trivial to get the CJC to track to within a couple degrees either.

Comment: You must be right, I'm not sure how to convert +/- 8 LSB error to degrees.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Resolution is 0.25°C, so just divide by 4.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure and have never tested this but I saw a circuit years ago that used a diode 1N4148 as a temperature sensor. The idea is that you put a resistor in series with the diode and measure the voltage across the resistor. This should vary slightly as the diode's forward voltage changes slightly with temperature.
Maybe someone can try this an see it it really works. You need a very stable voltage source obviously.  Anyway good luck and I hope it works.
The only other cheap solution I can think of is using a thermistor.

Comment: When you elect to use a diode like a 1N4148 as a temperature sensor you want to bias the diode with a 1mA constant current source. You then measure the voltage across the diode. If your A/D converter range is larger than the diode forward voltage range over temperature then you use an opamp to get some gain and increase the range.

Comment: I doubt any silicon rectifier can withstand such an high temperature (200°C) without damage, at least on the long run. One datasheet I have states that 1N4148 has an absolute operating AND storage temperature range of -65°C..175°C.